# Aborted connection to db: user: host: 'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets)

Tags: mariadb, errors, connections

For some time now I'm getting said error from a WooCommerce installation of mine. Since the answers I found to this problem are not applicable or very old I opened my own topic. The WooCommerce Version is up-to-date and the code pretty much untouched so I don't think its a programming error. Concerning the settings I already increased the values for
max_allowed_packet (256M)
interactive_timeout (6000)
max_connections (400)
What other causes could there be for this error and what else can I try to get rid of it?

Best hopeful regards
Daniel